# Does WebStorm have a design view

Tags: webstorm, design-view

Does WebStorm have a design view like Dreamweaver?

I have been searching for it for a while but no clear answer found.

If not, can you please suggest an alternative to Dreamweaver that has a design view?

Comment: Nope -- it does not have such WYSIWYG mode. It is more code oriented tool rather than "visual".

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of any IDE similar to DreamWeaver in terms of functionality?

Comment: Sorry, but all **IDEs** that I know are code oriented (IDEA family; NetBeans, Eclipse based, Visual Studio). Other popular advanced text editors (Sublime, VSC etc) are the same. If you really need WYSIWYG mode then I recommend to stick to Adobe products (Dreamweaver or Adobe Muse).

Comment: Better say -- why do you need such functionality? Are you new to the HTML/CSS (web dev)? Or you need to visualise your code to see the changes faster than usual "make-changes->save->go-to-browser->refresh"? If so -- try Live Reload (WebStorm has LiveEdit plugin -- works with Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

I use Hype on Mac. It seems to do a good job of the wysiwyg anytime I need to wireframe or run a quick UX design sequence. Whenever I sit down to code however it's visual code.

Answer (score 0):

I use GlueGriffon WYSIWYG to edit HTML pages that I create in WebStorm